# Storing and retrieving new line '\n' in XML files

Tags: javascript, xml, xml-serialization

I am saving a text element in an XML file.  Within the XML file, there are line breaks within the text node as follows

```
<text text="This is
a new line." fontsize="20">
```

However, when I load the XML file, using loadXMLDoc(), I use

```
textStr=textElem.getAttribute("text");
thisChar=textStr.charAt(i);
console.log('thisChar='+thisChar+'='+thisChar.charCodeAt(0));
```

to see if the '\n' characters have been retained and find that they have been replaced by spaces. (That is thisChar.charCodeAt(0) gives a value of 32 instead of a value of 10.)

What is the best way to save and retrieve new lines in text elements using XML?

Comment: Newline characters are treated as undifferentiated white space in PCDATA content. In a sense, they're not really there in the first place. If you need to store line breaks, you can either set the content up as CDATA or else use some explicit XML tags to indicated explicit line breaks.

Comment: Thank you for your reply.  I decided to take the latter approach.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a text node, it's an attribute node. The difference is crucial. In attributes, whitespace is automatically normalized by the XML parser - the details depend on how the attribute is described in the DTD, but by default newlines are replaced by spaces.